# read environment variables from whitelist and pipe to sed

Tags: bash, sed

I've got a whitelist file of env variables that looks like this:

```
ENV_A
ENV_B
ENV_C
```

I have another file `filetoreplace.txt` that (let's say) looks like this:

```
asdfasdfasdfasdf{{ENV_A}}asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf

adsfasdf
asdf{{ENV_B}}
asdf{{ENV_A}}
adsfasdfdsfdf{{ENV_C}}
```

I want to come up with a (one line) sed command that reads the variable names from the file and does the replacement.

For this environment

```
ENV_A=1
ENV_B=2
ENV_C=3
```

This would be the output given the above file

```
asdfasdfasdfasdf1asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf

adsfasdf
asdf2
asdf1
adsfasdfdsfdf3
```

I think it's kind of similar to this:

```
< whitelist | while read var; do
  sed -i 's/{{'"$var"'}}/'${!var}'/g' filetoreplace.txt
done
```

Looking for a bit of code golf to do this in a one liner here

Comment: Note that (1) we frown on code golf here; SO is limited to "_practical_, answerable" questions, and compromising correctness, robustness and readability for terseness is inherently impractical. (2) Is there a reason you don't change your format a bit and use envsubst?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - fair point, but your comment is exactly what I was looking for, I'm sure you know from my previous questions you've helped me on that I'm really out of my comfort zone in bash, so I was completely unaware of the possibility of `envsubst` - how can I use it?

Comment: There are already templating tools that do this kind of replacement for your; don't try to write your own using `sed`.

Comment: @chepner - thanks. I'd love to know what they are? If it helps, I need to run this as a command in a Docker container, I'm not looking to add any dependencies, if I can avoid it.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/replacing-only-specific-variables-with-envsubst (ignore the awful accepted answer in favor of the one with the upvotes).

Comment: BTW, `< whitelist |` is a zsh-ism, but this question is tagged bash. In bash, you need to put the `<whitelist` after the `done` to redirect from a file into a loop. (The practice works in zsh and POSIX sh too, so it's a good habit to be in to write portable code).

Comment: ...as another aside, you can pass multiple expressions to one copy of `sed`. Something like `operations=( ); while IFS= read -r val; do operations+=( -e "s/{{${var}}}/${!var}/g" ); done; (( ${#operations[@]} )) && sed -i "${operations[@]}" filetoreplace.txt` still has most of the bugs of the original proposal, but at least it's much faster (only runs `sed` once).

Answer (score 0):

Got 2 impractical variants based on your idea with $var\${!var}

First, obvy

```
vars=( $(cat whitelist) ); for var in ${vars[@]}; { sed "s|{{$var}}|${!var}|g" -i filetoreplace.txt; }
```

Second, monstrous)

```
vars=( $(cat filetoreplace.txt) ); for var in ${vars[@]}; { env=${var//[!ENV_ABC]/}; [[ $env ]] && val=${!env} || var=; echo ${var//"{{$env}}"/$val}; }
```

Comment: `array=(  $(anything) )` is buggy; see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). So is`${vars[@]}`; always quote as in `"${vars[@]}"`  or you have the same problems even after fixing how the assignment is done.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, As i've said 2 impractical variants, i just loved the idea of using $var\${!var} so i couldn't just pass by)

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple alternative solution :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bash -c "source whitelist; cat << EOF
$(perl -pe 's/\{(\{.*?})}/\$$1/' filetoreplace.txt)
EOF
"
```

The aim of the perl script is to transform `{{ENV_A}}` to `${ENV_A}`